What is the meaning "- modified column foo" in MySQL Workbench?
I tried to compare two schemas using "Compare and Report Differences in Catalogs" in MySQL Workbench and got a report with:
Table `users` was modified

columns:
  - modified column ip_address
  - modified column title
  - modified column first_name
  - modified column last_name
  - modified column preferred_name
  - modified column password

I tried to compare the columns manually and could not find any difference. It has the same, data type, charset, and collation. What is the meaning of this report?
